# My method isn't putting names into my array and removing them properly

Tags: arrays, stable-marriage

I've been working on the "Stable Marriage Problem" for a class I'm in and I cannot get it to implement the Gale-Shapely Algorithm correctly. The out put when prompted:

```
for (int q = 0; q < numMen; q++ ) 
System.out.println(couples[q].toString());
```

is 
"Brian Patricia
George Nancy
John Susan
Robert Nancy
Stephen Joyce"
only they are all on different lines. How ever the proper combination is "Brian Patricia George **Joyce** John Susan Robert Nancy Stephen **Anne**. The issue is it won't remove "Nancy" as George's pair. Also for background men[][] is the matrix of the men's preferences in the format men[i][0] is the name of each man for 0 < i < 4 and men[i][k] with k as the preferences in the positions 1 < k < 5. Same thing for the women matrix. Also couples[] is the array of object "couple" which is basically and array that holds each matched pair of a man and a woman. Here's the place where the problem is:

```
public static void SolveMenMarriages() {
    int i, k;
    String m, w, fiance;

    i = 0;
    fiance = null;
    while (i < numMen) {
        k = 1;

        m = men[i][0];
        w = men[i][k];

        if (isProposedTo(w))
            fiance = findFiance(w);

        if (!isProposedTo(w)) {
            couples[i] = new couple(m, w);
            i++;
        } else if (checkPreferenceWoman(fiance, m, w).equals(m)){
            couples[i] = new couple(m, w);
            removeFiance(fiance);
            i = fianceIndex(fiance); 
        } else {
            k++;
        }

        if (i == (numMen - 1)) {
            for(int v = 0; v < numMen; v++) {
                if (couples[v].woman == null)
                    i = 0;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
public static String checkPreferenceWoman(String M1, String M2, String w) {
    int c;

    c = 0;
    while (c < numWomen) {
        if (women[c][0].equals(w)) {
            for (int d = 1; d < (numMen + 1); d++) {
                if (women[c][d].equals(M2)) {
                    return M2;
                } 
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
    return M1;
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: The problem lies within the algorithm itself. I've looked over it a hundred times and in my head this should work. i was hoping a new set of eye could see the problem a bit more clearly lol.